# Easy way to detect android:minSdkVersion automatically?

Tags: android

I'm not too familiar with which features belonging to which android version. Is there an easy way to discover the lowest version of android that my app can run in?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [lint](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html) tool. 
Try to set `minSdkVersion` to 1 and run lint.
It'll show all methods and objects which later API is required for.

Comment: there is a button to run it directly from eclipse - it's icon looks like checkbox

Answer (score 0):

`android:minSdkVersion` — Specifies the minimum API Level on which the application is able to run. The default value is "1".

Before setting the minimum sdk version please check the scenario here. You can detect it programmatically .

http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by detecting.. its up to you that which minimum api level you want your app to be supported. select any **android:minSdkVersion**  e.g 8,10 etc. If any of the feature you are using which is not supported on this api level Eclipse will automatically tell, else use Android Lint

Answer (score -1):

The minimum SDK version is the one you declare in your manifest for example  the following line will set the minimum SDK version of your app to 7.

Comment: I know, but I want to find out the lowest value I can set without having to test manually for each Avd in emulartorn.

Answer (score -1):

you can't discover like this. If you want to test your app in all versions of avds

set your app `minSdkVersion to 8` and `targetSdkVersion to 15`

- create all all versions of Android Virtual machines(avd) which you want to test
- run your app in all versions of avds which you have created by selecting android target

Comment: Was thinking something like this but without having to do it manually;-) Ex Eclipse gives a warning that a feature in my app is not supported in the version I specified in the manifest.

Answer (score -1):

No way to do it programmatically.